# Using unity Asp.Net MVC bootstrapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container

In my ASP.Net MVC 5 application using VS 2013, I am using Unity MVC bootstrapper  [package id="Unity.Mvc"] which is in other dll. Not sure, which is not working.

The similar setup is working VS 2012 + ASp.Net MVC 4 application and same package.

Can some body help me in resolving this? Is unity bootstrap is compatible with Asp.Net MVC 5?

Comment: What do you mean by "which is in other dll"? Did you mean that the package installed in a separete dll and not in the web app? Either way ASP.NET MVC5 with the Unity.Mvc should work. I have no trouble installing into my ASP.NET MVC 5 app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. Thanks for the responses. It is something wrong with my setup.  My output binary (dll) is not copying into the web project folder as I gave the folder path wrong while upgrading. One more issue I observed to resolve is system.Web.http binding is failing. So I need to have the bind attribute in my web.config file.

```
<assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
</assemblyBinding>`
```